# How much of the frontend functionality should be mirrored in the API?

Tags: api, testing, dependencies

QA here. Relatively new to API testing (manual). Thought I'd turn to the experts to try and figure out if my expectations around how much functionality *should* sit in the API are more or less valid.
More specifically, I'm testing dependencies ie.

if input_field_1 = No then input field 2 should be read-only

if input_field_1 = Yes then input field 2 should be enabled

I'd expect that if I didn't change the value from No to Yes in the API for input_field_1, then trying to manipulate the value of input_field_2 would have no effect and should not be updated when the call is executed. This is not the case.

My devs say that this logic is not necessary in the API because it is handled by the frontend and if an input field is read-only (dependent on another field), it would essentially never pass through a value in the first place. They also say that the API is basically impenetrable and no one would ever be carrying out this sort of manipulation (but I am). I understand the first half of this sentiment, but I'm still reluctant to omit these edge cases in the API. Essentially, I am able to update fields that should be read-only in the API and those changes are pulling through to the frontend. This doesn't seem technically sound or correct to me.

Comment: What kind of API is it (web api?) and how exposed is it ? Can anyone build an URL (for exemple) passing input1 and inpuit2 as parameters and manipulate 2 with 1 set to no like you did ?

Comment: Yes JayZ, it is a WebAPI. It will only be accessible in an internal work group network using AD. Yes to the 2nd question as well - anyone is capable of manipulating the params..

Answer (score 11):

**Data must always be validated again in the backend, even if it is already validated in the frontend.**

The fundamental principle at work here is this: *you cannot trust the frontend.*  It could contain a bug or virus.  It might not be your frontend at all; it might be some other program written by a bad actor to gain access to your systems.

So why validate in the frontend?  For convenience.  Front-end programs are meant to promote better user interaction; this includes avoiding a round trip to the server to validate data.

The API is not impenetrable just because your developers say it is.  It is *reasonably secure* because your tests say it is.

Comment: That being said, you're technically not _mirroring_ your test between backend and frontend. The backend and frontend test their own validation. If one of them doesn't have a validation (and you have a valid point that they usually should, or at least definitely the backend and _maybe_ the frontend too), then you don't write a test for that validation there.

Comment: Data must always be validated again in the backend, even if it is already validated in the frontend. <-- I've been trying to stress this to the devs, but they say that it is enough for it to be handled by the frontend exclusively.

Comment: There is less peril if the API is internal, but it still does not constitute a secure system.  The API should be self-contained; it should not depend on anything else for its proper functioning, including validation from a frontend system.

Comment: The reason I make mention of the frontend is because if an input field is read-only there, shouldn't it effectively be the same in the WebAPI? Most of the research I've done says the actions I conduct in the API should be indicative of what would happen in the frontend.. Surely if the key value pair in the API has a value of null, is read-only and then is updated to a value of "Active"; executing that call should revert the value to null. I just want to check on what is best practice here and know that I'm not nuts for being so anal haha! :P

Comment: `if an input field is read-only there, shouldn't it effectively be the same in the WebAPI?` -- Well, why is it read-only in the frontend?  Are there compelling reasons for that field to be read-only?  If those reasons also apply to the API itself (and not just to this particular frontend program), then the API still needs its own validation.

Comment: In this particular scenario, very compelling reasons. Read-only on the frontend to prohibit a workflow from moving forward. The devs have also told me that a good WebAPI should be able to function on it's own if the frontend framework is removed for whatever reason and replaced. That has really stuck with me, but when I challenge them and use their own words as motivation, they pick and choose which scenarios it's applicable to. You've been a great help Mr. Harvey. Thank you so much!

Comment: "your frontend ... might be some other program written by a bad actor to gain access to your systems." - this should be in boldface text! I cannot tell you how many times I've explained to developers that the front end or UI is _**not**_ the only way to get to your backend, and if someone is trying to hack the system, the UI is _**not**_ the only way they will try to get to your backend.

Comment: @Jasmine: The problem with such issues is, they are neither a clear bug nor a missing feature, they are a potential security risk. Your team, maybe together with your superiors, should clarify which priority they want to give to each of these three categories. If they want potential security risks to be very low prioritized (which, for certain kinds of software, can be perfectly fine), just file your defect report in your team's issue tracker, so it can be found later when someone decides to change that priorities..

Comment: The team says that there aren't any security risks because it is an internal work group on an internal network. They have their own servers that the cloud based system sits on that is accessed through AD. I'm not too well versed in networking, so it sounds secure to me. Is it though?